# NextAuth session is returning null when using custom OAuth Provider (Trackmania)

Tags: typescript, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth

I am trying to implement OAuth using Trackmania as my custom provider. I am following the documentation as stated [here](https://webservices.openplanet.dev/oauth/auth#user/ui-flow). I am getting all the way to the end of the section where it states I should be seeing a resposne like this:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "access_token": "TOKEN",
  "refresh_token": "TOKEN"
}
```

And I do see it being logged in the terminal.

The Trackmania API does support OpenID, and you can see that by going to this link [here](https://api.trackmania.com/.well-known/openid-configuration). So, I setup my provider as close to the one in the [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider) as possible:

```
import type { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const options: AuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in",
    signOut: "/sign-out"
  },
  providers: [
    {
      id: "trackmania",
      name: "Trackmania",
      type: "oauth",
      wellKnown: "https://api.trackmania.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: {
        params: {
          response_type: "code",
          client_id: process.env.TM_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "write_favorite",
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/auth-return"
        },
        url: "https://api.trackmania.com/oauth/authorize"
      },
      // idToken: true,
      // checks: ["state"],
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        console.log("profile: ", profile);
        console.log("tokens: ", tokens);

        return {
          ...profile,
          ...tokens
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.TM_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TM_OAUTH_SECRET_ID,
      issuer: "https://api.trackmania.com/",
      token: {
        url: "https://api.trackmania.com/api/access_token"
      },
      userinfo: {
        url: "https://api.trackmania.com/api/user"
      }
    }
  ],
  // secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  }
};
```

On my sign-in page, all I have is a simple heading and a `SignInButton` component, which looks like this:

```
"use client";

import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const SignInButton = () => {
  return (
    <button
      className="border-2 border-blue-600 inline-block mt-4 py-2 px-4 rounded-md text-blue-600 font-bold hover:bg-blue-600 hover:text-white transition-colors"
      onClick={() => signIn("trackmania")}
      type="button"
    >
      Sign In With OAuth
    </button>
  );
};

export default SignInButton;
```

In my Trackmania OAuth App, I've set the Homepage to `http://localhost:3000/`, and the Redirect Uris to just `http://localhost:3000/api/user/auth-return`.

In my project, I've setup a `route.ts` file at the following location: `src/app/api/user/auth-return/route.ts`.

Here is the code for it (it handles the `POST` request as outlined in the docs linked above):

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  console.log("request headers: ", request.headers);

  const code = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("code") || "";

  const url = "https://api.trackmania.com/api/access_token";
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      client_id: process.env.TM_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.TM_OAUTH_SECRET_ID,
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/auth-return"
    })
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    const text = await res.text(); // get the response body for more information

    throw new Error(`
      Failed to fetch data
      Status: ${res.status}
      Response: ${text}
    `);
  }

  const data = await res.json();
  console.log("data: ", data);
  // return NextResponse.json(data);

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/profile", request.url));
};
```

The issue is when I go to a page like the profile page, which looks like this:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { options } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options";

const ProfilePage = async () => {
  const session = await getServerSession(options);

  console.log("session: ", session);

  return (
    <div className="pl-4">
      <h1 className="text-2xl">ProfilePage</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am seeing `session: null` being logged. After lots of tinkering and Googling, I believe the issue is with the cookies? The `next-auth.session-token` is not replacing the `next-auth.state cookie`, and I cannot figure out why. And after some more Googling tonight, I think the issue is possible due to how cookies are set server-side? Here is a link to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/andrews1022/demo-nextjs-13-nextauth-custom-pages-with-custom-oauth) with all the code.

Lastly, here is my `.env.local` file:

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET="ID_GENERATED_FROM_OPENSSL_RAND"
NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000/"

TM_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID="..."
TM_OAUTH_SECRET_ID="..."
```

I am fairly new to all of this, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!